# No progress inTomcat7 after Deploying web application directory in linux

Tags: linux, web-server, java, tomcat7

Hi I am new to linux environment.

Initially we had all the application working on a virtual machine. Due to some reasons we did not used it for a while.
So after a long gap when we try to check that machine our tomcat was not running. There were progress in Tomcat7 after "Deploying web application directory".
I also tried to install the tomcat server 7.0.35 and jre 1.7 again but no luck.

I will paste all the logs and steps taken to run apache server below:

```
[myName@nalnx123456789 ~]$ sudo /usr/local/sbin/tomcat
 --- Switching users ---
User Name     :  tomcat
UID           :  602
Home Dir      :  /usr/local/tomcat
[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~% ll
total 4
drwxrwxr-x 9 tomcat tomcat 4096 Oct 16 08:41 apache-tomcat-7.0.35
[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~% cd apache-tomcat-7.0.35

[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~/apache-tomcat-7.0.35% cd bin
[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin% sh startup.sh
Using CATALINA_BASE:   /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35
Using CATALINA_HOME:   /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35
Using CATALINA_TMPDIR: /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/temp
Using JRE_HOME:        /usr
Using CLASSPATH:       /usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin/bootstrap.jar:/usr/local/tomcat/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin/tomcat-juli.jar
[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/bin% cd ..
[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~/apache-tomcat-7.0.35% cd logs

[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs% ll
total 6
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 1283 Oct 16 08:43 catalina.2015-10-16.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat 2556 Oct 19 01:23 catalina.out
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat    0 Oct 16 08:43 host-manager.2015-10-16.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat    0 Oct 16 08:43 localhost.2015-10-16.log
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat    0 Oct 16 08:43 localhost_access_log.2015-10-16.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 tomcat tomcat    0 Oct 16 08:43 manager.2015-10-16.log

[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs% cat catalina.out
Oct 16, 2015 8:43:02 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.ClassLoaderFactory validateFile
WARNING: Problem with directory [/usr/local/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.35_old1/lib/properties], exists: [false], isDirectory: [false], canRead: [false]
Oct 16, 2015 8:43:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.AprLifecycleListener init
INFO: The APR based Apache Tomcat Native library which allows optimal performance in production environments was not found on the java.library.path: /usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
Oct 16, 2015 8:43:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["http-bio-8085"]
Oct 16, 2015 8:43:03 AM org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol init
INFO: Initializing ProtocolHandler ["ajp-bio-8009"]
Oct 16, 2015 8:43:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.Catalina load
INFO: Initialization processed in 827 ms
Oct 16, 2015 8:43:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardService startInternal
INFO: Starting service Catalina
Oct 16, 2015 8:43:03 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine startInternal
INFO: Starting Servlet Engine: Apache Tomcat/7.0.35
Oct 16, 2015 8:43:03 AM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory
INFO: Deploying web application directory /usr/local/tomcat7/apache-tomcat-7.0.35_old1/webapps/manager


Java Version:
[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs% java -version
java version "1.7.0_13"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_13-b20)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 23.7-b01, mixed mode)
[tomcat@nalnx123456789]~/apache-tomcat-7.0.35/logs%
```

Kindly help me to get me some clue to fix this issue.

Thanks in advance